# is there a chance that malware will affect my windows partitions?

Tags: windows, malware

My question is :
Same I dismount?
affect my windows partitions?
Sorry my english grammar

Comment: Thank you by your help

Comment: If you are asking if you unmount Windows and use Ubuntu and pick up some malware in Ubuntu, the answer should be unlikely for windows to get it.  Malware will probably not harm Ubuntu, but it will be around and you could pass to windows afterwards if you mount and copy something from ubuntu to windows.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, does Windows OS mount Linux partition? Can you copy files to Windows partitions? There are some chances depend on the condition.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**

Some malware can delete or encrypt/ransom your entire system -- all partitions, including Windows, Ubuntu, and others.

It's unlikely that a virus will try to mount Windows partitions and infect your Windows install. There are several layers of protection to prevent that kind of intrusion, and the number of dual-boot systems is a bit low to justify such effort. Such malware is possible, but has not been seen in the wild.

Use good security habits, including proper backups and good reinstallation notes, to avoid becoming a very frustrated victim.